# How to make this javascript ordering consecutive integers ascending by swaps function more efficient?

Tags: javascript, coding-efficiency

Object is to order ascending an unordered list of consecutive integers 1,2,3.....n by swapping numbers (say swapping values at indices 3 and 6), and find the minimum number of swaps needed. My code works, but times out (10 second limit) when given the edge case 100000 integers. How can I streamline this code? To me it feels fairly minimal already - no nested loops or anything. I'm not very experienced with efficiency evaluation, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
function minimumSwaps(arr) {
    var swaps = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] !== i+1) {
            var tempIndex = arr.indexOf(i+1);
            var tempVal = arr[i];
            arr[i] = i+1;
            arr[tempIndex] = tempVal;
            swaps += 1;
    }
  }
  //console.log(swaps)
  return swaps;
}
```

Comment: Is this helpful? [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-number-swaps-required-sort-array/)

Comment: "order ascending" is called [sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)

Comment: "*no nested loops or anything*" - but there's an `indexOf` call in the loop, which is essentially a nested loop.

Comment: thanks ProGu but that code uses more iteration than I do (it has to handle more possibilities than I do though so it may be the best for those constraints). I'm looking for less iteration, I see the for and indexOf as indispensable but they must not be